How do I make my VPS recognize my printer?
I have a VPS in hostinguer using Linux, and I have mounted an app.
One of the functionality is that I have an endpoint that prints a file. The problem is, my local printer is not being recognized even though i have CUPS.

I have found solutions, but they apply to Windows VPS. Does someone have a possible solution for Linux?

I have tried this
root@host ~# sudo ldadmin -p EPSON_L450 -E -v lpd://192.168.1.14/ENPQueue -m everywhere
lpadmin: Unable to connect to "192.168.1.14:515": Connection timed out



I also tried using drivers, with the same result, the IP is not found


Is there anything I can do?

Are you connecting with ssh? Does your VPS need to print even when you're not connected with ssh? (I'm thinking we could maybe tunnel CUPS across the ssh connection.)

Do not post text as images.

Assuming that

You're connecting with ssh
The VPS doesn't need to print except when you're connected
Your local machine can reach the printer on 192.168.1.14

We could tunnel the CUPS connection across your ssh connection from your local system, and print that way.
Your usual connection:
ssh user@remoteVPS

The modified version to include a CUPS printing tunnel:
ssh -R 50515:192.168.1.14:515 user@remoteVPS

Now on the remote VPS you set up CUPS as usual but have it print to a printer on localhost, port 50515 (instead of port 515):
lpadmin -p EPSON_L450 -E -v lpd://127.0.0.1:50515/ENPQueue -m everywhere

